# Validating Input in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code

```js
<div>
    <button ng-click="myController.addEmptyStudent()">+</button>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="student in myController.students">
    <input type="text" ng-model='student['Name']" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model='student['Address']" required>
</div>
```

Now, Since it is creating input boxes when I click on (+) plus button. 
I want to validate that no two **Names** are same before submitting the
form.

Comment: Can you add your `myController` code? It could help a lot

Comment: Please share what you have tried.. you should create a Validator if you are using Forms.. take a look here for more details: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: myController code is just adding the empty object of student inside students array. something like students.push({ "Name": ''", "Address": ""}) when button clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. 
Changes in controller

```
    function studentNameChanged() {
        vm.duplicateNames = false;
        let studentNamesArray = students.map(item => item['studentName']);
        vm.duplicateNames = studentNamesArray.some( (item, index) => {
            return (studentNamesArray.indexOf(item) !== index)
        });
    }
```

Changes in HTML file

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="myController.addEmptyStudent()">+</button>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="student in myController.students">
    <input type="text" ng-change="myController.studentNameChanged()" ng-model="student['Name']" required>
    <input type="text" ng-model="student['Address']" required>
</div>
<div>
   <div style="color:red;" ng-show="myController.duplicateNames">
   Attribute Names must be different
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mistyped quotes. Your  code

```
<input type="text" ng-model='student['Name']" required>
```

This should be:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="student['Name']" required>
<input type="text" ng-model="student.Name" required> // or like that
```